# Conditional insert sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Let's consider this basic insert

```
insert into TableName (Col1,Col2,Col3) values (Val1,Val2,Val3)
```

i want this insert to be done only if Val1 !=null and Val3!=null
How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
IF (Val1 is not null AND Val3 is not null)
BEGIN 
    insert into TableName (Col1,Col2,Col3) values (Val1,Val2,Val3)
END
```

On second thought BeachBlocker's answer is quite nice too. I've modified it a little:

```
insert into TableName (Col1,Col2,Col3) select Val1,Val2,Val3 where Val1 is not null and Val3 is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into TableName (Col1,Col2,Col3) select Val1,Val2,Val3 where Val1 is not null and Val3 is not null
```